# HOW TO WORK ON SQLITE DATABASE IN DJANGO?

Tags: django, database, sqlite

I am new to programming i am trying to add product through my admin panel but i am getting this error:
    no such table found
    [I am using python version 3.8.2
    Django version==3.0.7
    and i am getting this error: No such table found][1]
    thanks for help

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayhGa.png
```

Comment: Have you run `python manage.py migrate`?

Answer (score 0):

you can inspect the created databses with the [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/).

Did you run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` after you editied or created a model?
Also be sure, to include any new app in the `installed_app` list in the `settings.py` of your project.